# Why is height: 100% and width 100% not working

Tags: css

I want to make the `background-color` for a **DIV not body** light gray and another div inside it dark gray. I tried the following:

  - Setting the first div width and height to 100%
  - Setting the first div min-width and min-height to 100%
  - Setting the first div max-width and max-height to 100%
  - Setting html and the first div width and height to 100

```css
.div1 {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.div2 {

    background: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which div do you want to be 100%?  And have you tried adding `position: absolute;` to `.div1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `html` and `body` dimensions.

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

updated code:

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.div1 {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.div2 {

    background: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```